# TypeScript: How can I fix a type issue with using `.length` to count the characters or a component's `children`?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following code to count the length of text within my component's `children` and add a class:

```
className={clsx(classes.text, {
   [classes.textSmall]: children?.length ?? 0 > 11,
})}
```

This works but I get a TypeScript error on `.length`.

> Property 'length' does not exist on type 'number'.ts(2339)

I am not sure how to address this as `children` don't really have type.

Would anyone know what I should be doing?

Comment: Maybe someone else can figure it out from just this, but I suspect we need more context. Could you include the other parts of the component where `children` comes from?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `children` is of type `number`, and you're trying to find its length. This fails as there is no `.length` property on `number`. You can get around this by converting this to a string first, and then checking its length like so:

```js
className={clsx(classes.text, {
   [classes.textSmall]: (`${children}`)?.length ?? 0 > 11,
})}
```